# Delete duplicates in list of tuples

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a long list of tuples as shown below.  They are all different permutations of a group of n numbers.  I only want to element of the same group of numbers regardless of order.  Is there an easy way to delete those duplicates?

```
    [('2',), ('3',), ('5',), ('4',), ('2', '3'), ('2', '5'), ('2', '4'), 
     ('3', '2'), ('3', '5'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '2'), ('5', '3'), ('5', '4'), 
('4', '2'), ('4', '3'), ('4', '5'), ('2', '3', '5'), ('2', '3', '4'), ('2', '5', '3'), 
('2', '5', '4'), ('2', '4', '3'), ('2', '4', '5'), ('3', '2', '5'), ('3', '2', '4'), 
('3', '5', '2'), ('3', '5', '4'), ('3', '4', '2'), ('3', '4', '5'), ('5', '2', '3'), 
('5', '2', '4'), ('5', '3', '2'), ('5', '3', '4'), ('5', '4', '2'), ('5', '4', '3'), 
('4', '2', '3'), ('4', '2', '5'), ('4', '3', '2'), ('4', '3', '5'), ('4', '5', '2'), 
('4', '5', '3'), ('2', '3', '5', '4'), ('2', '3', '4', '5'), ('2', '5', '3', '4'), 
('2', '5', '4', '3'), ('2', '4', '3', '5'), ('2', '4', '5', '3'), ('3', '2', '5', '4'), 
('3', '2', '4', '5'), ('3', '5', '2', '4'), ('3', '5', '4', '2'), ('3', '4', '2', '5'), 
('3', '4', '5', '2'), ('5', '2', '3', '4'), ('5', '2', '4', '3'), ('5', '3', '2', '4'), 
('5', '3', '4', '2'), ('5', '4', '2', '3'), ('5', '4', '3', '2'), ('4', '2', '3', '5'), 
('4', '2', '5', '3'), ('4', '3', '2', '5'), 
     ('4', '3', '5', '2'), ('4', '5', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '3', '2')]
```